# Как разрезать строку по нескольким символам?

Tags: javascript

Нужно сделать функцию которая разобьет строку по нескольким символам

**Например:**

`console.log(YourFunction('4 + (2 - (1 + 3) - 2) + 12');`

`//output: ['4 +', '2 - ', '1 + 3', ' - 2', '+ 12']`

В моём коде появляется `undefined`

P.S: желательно сделать всё циклом

```js
function Expression(expression) {
  var exp = String(expression);

  var result = [];

  for (var i = 0, n = 0; i < exp.length; i++) {
    if (exp[i] == '(' || exp[i] == ')') {
      n++;
      i++;
    }
    result[n] += exp[i];
  }

  console.log(result);

}

Expression('4 + (2 - (1 + 3) - 2) + 12');
```

Comment: Нет никакого смысла так разбивать выражение.

Comment: @Qwertiy Почему?

Comment: Потому что эти фрагменты бесполезны для его вычисления.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну тогда как лучше реализовать парсер строки в фрагменты для вычисления? Например чтобы можно было оброботать сначала скобки, умножение. деление и только после додавание и вычисление, проще говоря научить решать простые математические задачи?

Comment: Нет, разбиваешь строку на токены `/\d+|[-+*/]/g` и дальнейшее вычисление делается рекурсивной функцией за один проход по полученному массиву.

Comment: @Qwertiy сложно -_-. split(/\d+|[-+*/]/g); так?

Comment: Не split, а match

Comment: Тьфу, скобки ещё: `/\d+|[-+*/()]/g`

Comment: Спасибо, попытаюсь розобраться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так работает правильно (выводится также и `" + 12"`):

```js
function expression(exp)
{
 var result = [],
  str = '',
  i = 0;

 for(; i < exp.length; i++)
 {
  if(exp[i] != '(' && exp[i] != ')')
   str += exp[i];
  else
  {
   result.push(str);
   str = '';
  }
 }
 result.push(str);
 return result
}

console.log(expression('4 + (2 - (1 + 3) - 2) + 12'));
```

**Примите во внимание:** имя функции в javascript принято писать с маленькой буквы, если она не является классом.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function expression(exp) {
  var result = [''];

  for (var i = 0, n = 0; i < exp.length; i++) {
    if (exp[i] == '(' || exp[i] == ')') {
      n++;
      result[n] = ''; // !!!
      i++;
    }
    result[n] += exp[i];
  }
  return result
}
console.log(expression('4 + (2 - (1 + 3) - 2) + 12'));
```

Comment: За что минусуют то?

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов демократия в действии :)

Comment: @Igor я не заметил функцию в коде)

Answer (score 1):

вот как мне кажется, более читабельный вариант

```js
function Expression(exp) {
  let result = [];

  let str = "";
  for (let c of exp) {
    if (!(c == "(" || c == ")")) str += c;
    else {
      result.push(str);
      str = "";
    }
  }

  return result;
}

let res = Expression("4 + (2 - (1 + 3) - 2) + 12");

console.log(res);
```

Comment: чего-то здесь не хватает